# Porting C code for an iOS app

Tags: ios, porting

I am working on building an app that needs to use a C library that I have.The C code is designed for Linux platform and has Linux system calls.

Firstly, I would need to port this C code to run on iOS. Is it possible to do so? Are iOS apps allowed to use system calls? (I read elsewhere that apps using syscall.h are not permitted on the appstore)

Secondly, once I have ported the code can I include them directly in my swift code? Or would I have to create .so files or any such thing.

Comment: iOS is a very different platform from Linux in many ways. What does the library do exactly?

Comment: It performs memory allocation/deallocation, socket communication etc.